# How to check if a string from 1st table is present in 2nd table with different extension?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and the first table contains a column with filenames with format 'Filename.error'. The second table contains filenames with the format 'Filename.tm'. I want to see if the filenames from the first table are present in the 2nd table with .tm format. How can it be accomplished?

Comment: Using `REPLACE`? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: A regular expression like this might help you? `^.*(?=\..*)`

Comment: Remove the extension from both and check for equality...?

Comment: @VvdL SQL Server has no (built in) support for regular expressions, so it is unlikely to help *unless* the OP have CLR Regex objects on their instance.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this query to get only the 'Filename' and similarly use it for other table to get only 'FileName', then use join to get the common tables*

```
SELECT  FileNameColumn
        ,SUBSTRING(FileNameColumn,-6,Len(FileNameColumn))
        AS  FileNameColumn_trimmed
FROM 
        TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last 5 characters (ie "error"), then add "tm" and search for that:

```
select
  a.filename,
  case when exists(
    select *
    from table2 b
    where b.filename = substr(a.filename, 1, len(a.filename) - 5) + 'tm'
  ) then 'Y' else 'N' end as tm_exists
from table1
```